# Inconsistency in Tableau Dashboard Data

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a tableau dashboard (Tableau Cloud) and have come across a weird issue.

Under the view mode the dashboard is showing incorrect number but when I open in edit mode the numbers change to the correct one

[View mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VV3R.png)

Some additional information: I have a website which links to the dashboard. when redirecting to the dashboard via the website I apply the filters through url query parameters. I checked if there is any issue here and I saw that all filters have been correctly applied.

[edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EM3E.png)

1.) I tried refreshing the data-source.
2.) I checked to see if the filters have been applied correctly. with the same filters the values shown in view and edit mode are different.

I am expecting the values to be correct and consistent.

Comment: What number it shows in your local machine before publishing?

Comment: Its showing the correct numbers on the desktop.